# Modular arithmetic in python to iterate a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Ok, I have a big dataframe such as:

```
      hour    value
  0      0      1
  1      6      2
  2     12      3
  3     18      4
  4      0      5
  5      6      6
  6     12      7
  7     18      8
  8      6      9
  9     12     10
 10     18     11
 11     12     12
 12     18     13
 13      0     14
```

Let's don't get lost here. The column `hour` represents the hours of the day, from 6 to 6 hours. Column `values` is well, exactly that, here the values are as an example, not the actual ones.

If you look closely to the `hour` column, you can see that there are hours missing. For instance, there is a gap between rows 7 and 8 (the value of hour 0 is missing). There are also bigger gaps, such as in  between rows 10 and 11 (hours 00 and 06).

**What do I need?** I would like to check when an hour (and of course) a value is missing, and complete the dataframe inserting a row there with the corresponding hour and a `np.nan` as value.

**What have I thought?** I think this would be easily solved using *modular arithmetic*, in this case with mod 24, such as when `18 + 6 = 24 = 0 mod 24`. So initializing the counter to zero and adding 6 *with the caveat that the counter is defined in modular arithmetic mod 24* you can verify if each `hour` is the corresponding hour, and if not, insert a new row with the corresponding hour and with `np.nan` as value.

I don't know how to do the implementation of modular arithmetic in python to iterate a dataframe column.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You could use `reindex` with an input such as `n * [0, 6, 12, 18]`. You would need to make `hour` the index first.

Comment: @IanS you need to identify which groups of rows constitute a day otherwise, you get `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Comment: And how do you know if you have a gap of four missing rows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Solution

```
group_hours = (df.hour <= df.hour.shift()).cumsum()

def insert_missing_hours(df):
    return df.set_index('hour').reindex([0, 6, 12, 18]).reset_index()

df.groupby(group_hours).apply(insert_missing_hours).reset_index(drop=1)
```

Looks like:

```
    hour  value
0      0    1.0
1      6    2.0
2     12    3.0
3     18    4.0
4      0    5.0
5      6    6.0
6     12    7.0
7     18    8.0
8      0    NaN
9      6    9.0
10    12   10.0
11    18   11.0
12     0    NaN
13     6    NaN
14    12   12.0
15    18   13.0
16     0   14.0
17     6    NaN
18    12    NaN
19    18    NaN
```

## Explanation

In order to apply `reindex` I needed to determine which rows to group.  I checked to see if row's hour was less or equal than prior row's hour.  If so, that flags a new group.

`insert_missing_hours` is precisely the `reindex` of subgroups with `[0, 6, 12, 18]`.

Answer (score 4):

Although this solution is more complex, it should be much more efficient, especially for larger dataframes.  This solution creates a list of hours and values (including any filled hours) and then uses this list to produce a dataframe.

```
def hour_checker(hours, values):
    def check_hour(hour):
        if hour not in (0, 6, 12, 18):
            raise ValueError('Invalid hour')
    [check_hour(hour) for hour in hours]
    result = []
    valid_hours = np.arange(0, 24, 6)
    while valid_hours[-1] != hour:
        # Initialize.
        valid_hours = np.roll(valid_hours, -1)
        result.append([hours.iat[0], values.iat[0]])
    for hour, value in zip(hours.iloc[1:], values.iloc[1:]):
        while hour != valid_hours[0]:
            result.append([valid_hours[0], None])
            valid_hours = np.roll(valid_hours, -1)
        result.append([hour, value])
        valid_hours = np.roll(valid_hours, -1)
    return pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['hour', 'value'])

hour_checker(df['hour'], df['value'])
Out[33]: 
    hour  value
0      0      1
1      6      2
2     12      3
3     18      4
4      0      5
5      6      6
6     12      7
7     18      8
8      0    NaN
9      6      9
10    12     10
11    18     11
12     0    NaN
13     6    NaN
14    12     12
15    18     13
16     0     14
```

**Timings**

```
df_test = pd.concat([df] * 100)

%%timeit
group_hours = (df_test.hour <= df_test.hour.shift()).cumsum()
df_test.groupby(group_hours).apply(insert_missing_hours).reset_index(drop=1)
1 loops, best of 3: 611 ms per loop

%timeit hour_checker(df_test['hour'], df_test['value'])
100 loops, best of 3: 12.4 ms per loop
```