# I need to change the format of the current Dataframe. How should i do this?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe as below:

```
In [14]: grouped_data
Out[14]: 
  monthyear Facility       Date       Yield 
0    Dec 15     CCM1 2015-12-01  2550.000000
1    Feb 16     CCM1 2016-02-01  4250.000000
2    Jan 16     CCM2 2016-01-01  1540.000000
3    Jan 16     CCM3 2016-01-01  6800.000000
4    Nov 15     CCM1 2015-11-01   921.458157
5    Nov 15     CCM2 2015-11-01  1750.310038
6    Sep 15     CCM3 2015-09-01  5191.197065
```

Now I need the dataframe to look like this:

```
  monthyear    CCM1      CCM2       CCM3         Date       
0  Dec 15  2550.000000    0          0        2015-12-01  
1  Feb 16  4250.000000    0          0        2016-02-01  
2  Jan 16     0       1540.000000 6800.000000 2016-01-01  
3  Nov 15  921.458157 1750.310038    0        2015-11-01  
4  Sep 15     0       5191.197065    0        2015-09-01
```

How will i do this with Pandas. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
print (df.pivot_table(index=['monthyear','Date'], 
                      columns='Facility', 
                      values='Yield',
                      fill_value=0))

Facility                     CCM1         CCM2         CCM3
monthyear Date                                             
Dec 15    2015-12-01  2550.000000     0.000000     0.000000
Feb 16    2016-02-01  4250.000000     0.000000     0.000000
Jan 16    2016-01-01     0.000000  1540.000000  6800.000000
Nov 15    2015-11-01   921.458157  1750.310038     0.000000
Sep 15    2015-09-01     0.000000     0.000000  5191.197065
```

If you want [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and remove columns name use [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
print (df.pivot_table(index=['monthyear','Date'], 
                      columns='Facility', 
                      values='Yield',
                      fill_value=0).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1))

  monthyear        Date         CCM1         CCM2         CCM3
0    Dec 15  2015-12-01  2550.000000     0.000000     0.000000
1    Feb 16  2016-02-01  4250.000000     0.000000     0.000000
2    Jan 16  2016-01-01     0.000000  1540.000000  6800.000000
3    Nov 15  2015-11-01   921.458157  1750.310038     0.000000
4    Sep 15  2015-09-01     0.000000     0.000000  5191.197065
```

But `pivot_table` uses `aggfunc`, default is `aggfunc=np.mean` if duplicates in columns `montyear` with `Date`. Better explanation with sample is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37436813/2901002) and in [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#pivot-tables).