# Python pandas pivot from long to wide

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, reshape

My data is currently in a long format. Below is a sample:

```
     Stock         Date      Time     Price     Year
       AAA   2001-01-05  15:20:09     2.380     2001
       AAA   2002-02-23  10:13:24     2.440     2002
       AAA   2002-02-27  17:17:55     2.460     2002
       BBB   2006-05-13  16:03:49     2.780     2006
       BBB   2006-10-04  10:33:10     2.800     2006
```

I would like to reshape it into a wide format by "Stock" and "Year" like so:

```
     Stock   Year       Date1        Time1    Price1        Date2      Time2   Price2
       AAA   2001  2001-01-05     15:20:09     2.380
       AAA   2002  2002-02-23     10:13:24     2.440   2002-02-27   17:17:55    2.460
       BBB   2006  2006-05-13     16:03:49     2.780   2006-10-04   10:33:10    2.800
```

I tried the solution posted here [Pandas long to wide reshape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798934/pandas-long-to-wide-reshape) and have this:

```
df['idx'] = df.groupby(['Stock', 'Year']).cumcount()

df['date_idx'] = 'date_' + df.idx.astype(str)
df['time_idx'] = 'time_' + df.idx.astype(str)
df['price_idx'] = 'price_' + df.idx.astype(str)

date = df.pivot(index=['Stock', 'Year'], columns='date_idx', values='Date')
time = df.pivot(index=['Stock', 'Year'], columns='time_idx', values='Time')
price = df.pivot(index=['Stock', 'Year'], columns='price_idx', values='Price')

reshape = pd.concat([date, time, price], axis=1)
```

but the last line gives me this error:

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 15624, placement implies 2

Where am I going wrong with my code? Or is there another cleaner way to do this reshape?

Comment: I included several examples [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47152691/2336654)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html), but need some `aggfunc`. I choose `first`, because there is problem use default `np.mean` with `datetime`.

Better explanation with sample is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37436813/2901002) and in [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#pivot-tables).

Solution1:

```
df['idx'] = (df.groupby(['Stock', 'Year']).cumcount() + 1).astype(str)

df1 = (df.pivot_table(index=['Stock', 'Year'], 
                      columns=['idx'], 
                      values=['Date', 'Time', 'Price'], 
                      aggfunc='first'))
df1.columns = [''.join(col) for col in df1.columns]
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
  Stock  Year       Date1       Date2     Time1     Time2 Price1 Price2
0   AAA  2001  2001-01-05        None  15:20:09      None   2.38   None
1   AAA  2002  2002-02-23  2002-02-27  10:13:24  17:17:55   2.44   2.46
2   BBB  2006  2006-05-13  2006-10-04  16:03:49  10:33:10   2.78    2.8
```

Then you can convert to `float` `price` columns and [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) `date` columns:

```
cols = df1.columns[df1.columns.str.contains('Price')]
df1[cols] = df1[cols].astype(float)

cols = df1.columns[df1.columns.str.contains('Date')]
df1[cols] = df1[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime)


print (df1)
  Stock  Year      Date1      Date2     Time1     Time2  Price1  Price2
0   AAA  2001 2001-01-05        NaT  15:20:09      None    2.38     NaN
1   AAA  2002 2002-02-23 2002-02-27  10:13:24  17:17:55    2.44    2.46
2   BBB  2006 2006-05-13 2006-10-04  16:03:49  10:33:10    2.78    2.80

print (df1.dtypes)
Stock             object
Year               int64
Date1     datetime64[ns]
Date2     datetime64[ns]
Time1             object
Time2             object
Price1           float64
Price2           float64
```

Solution2:

```
df['idx'] = df.groupby(['Stock', 'Year']).cumcount() + 1

df['date_idx'] = 'date_' + df.idx.astype(str)
df['time_idx'] = 'time_' + df.idx.astype(str)
df['price_idx'] = 'price_' + df.idx.astype(str)

date = df.pivot_table(index=['Stock', 'Year'], columns='date_idx', values='Date', aggfunc='first')
time = df.pivot_table(index=['Stock', 'Year'], columns='time_idx', values='Time', aggfunc='first')
price = df.pivot_table(index=['Stock', 'Year'], columns='price_idx', values='Price', aggfunc='first')

reshape = pd.concat([date, time, price], axis=1).reset_index()
print (reshape)
  Stock  Year      date_1      date_2    time_1    time_2  price_1  price_2
0   AAA  2001  2001-01-05        None  15:20:09      None     2.38      NaN
1   AAA  2002  2002-02-23  2002-02-27  10:13:24  17:17:55     2.44     2.46
2   BBB  2006  2006-05-13  2006-10-04  16:03:49  10:33:10     2.78     2.80
```