# Using more than one column for indexing in a pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I would like to combine two columns for index while pivoting a `pandas` `dataframe`. I'm using the following code to do so:

```
ConceptTemp = Concept.pivot(index=['memberid','testscoreid'], columns='questionid', values='correct')
```

this gives me the following error:

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1532, placement implies 2

1532 is the number of rows in my `dataframe`. I can't `pivot` only on `memberid` or on `testscoreid` as I'll have duplicate `questionid` values. The index column has to be a combination of `testscoreid` AND `memberid`.

Would anyone have any pointers on how to get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
ConceptTemp = Concept.pivot_table(index=['memberid','testscoreid'],
                                  columns='questionid', 
                                  values='correct')
```

`pivot_table` uses `aggfunc`, default is `aggfunc=np.mean` if duplicates. Better explanation with sample is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37436813/2901002) and in [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#pivot-tables).