# pandas group by: usage in this instance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

despite the extensive help provided [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) and [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) I was unable to figure out how to do the following:

given this dataset (df):

```
import pandas as pd
improt numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['CORE1', 'CORE2', 'CORE3', 'CORE1', 'CORE2', 'CORE3', 'CORE1', 'CORE2', 'CORE3', ],
                   ['alfa', 'beta', 'gamma', 'alfa', 'beta', 'gamma', 'alfa', 'beta', 'gamma', ],
                   np.random.rand(9).tolist()],
                  index=['ptf', 'name', 'value']).transpose()

name value ptf
alfa  0.1  CORE1
beta  0.7  CORE1
gamma 0.2  CORE1
alfa  0.3  CORE2
beta  0.4  CORE2
gamma 0.3  CORE2
alfa  0.9  CORE3
beta  0.05 CORE3
gamma 0.05 CORE3
```

turn into

```
      CORE1 CORE2 CORE3
alfa  0.1   0.3   0.9
beta  0.7   0.4   0.05
gamma 0.2   0.3   0.05
```

I was guessing somewhere in the lines of `df.groupby(by='ptf')` and something after. what exactly reamins to be understood.

Edit:

```
print(df.dtypes)

# 1st - works but takes numerate index - not what I want
print(df.pivot(columns='ptf', values='value'))
# 2nd - textbook made - does not work
print(df.pivot(index='name', columns='ptf', values='value'))
# 3rd - same as 2nd but with different constructor
print(pd.pivot_table(df, index='name', values='value', columns='ptf'))
```

Any help in the matter?

Comment: I always like to point to [this page](http://www.nikgrozev.org/2015/07/01/reshaping-in-pandas-pivot-pivot-table-stack-and-unstack-explained-with-pictures/) for a good introduction to pivoting and stacking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
print (df.pivot(index='name', columns='ptf', values='value'))
ptf    CORE1  CORE2  CORE3
name                      
alfa     0.1    0.3   0.90
beta     0.7    0.4   0.05
gamma    0.2    0.3   0.05
```

Comment: it's the right approach but I get the same error some users ecnounter here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232275/pandas-pivot-warning-about-repeated-entries-on-index) ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: You need `(df.pivot_table(index='name', columns='ptf', values='value'))` what uses `aggfunc`, default is `aggfunc=np.mean` if duplicates. Better explanation with sample is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37436813/2901002) and in [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#pivot-tables).

Comment: tried that as well. `Error in this case: pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`

Comment: What is `df.dtypes`? Column `values` contains numbers, but `dtype` is not `float`? Or column `values` contains some texts?

Comment: `print(df.dtypes)` `ptf      object
name     object
value    object
dtype: object`

Comment: First try convert column to float `df['value'] = df['value'].astype(float)`.

Comment: I edited the original psot with more data. `df['value'] = df['value'].astype(float)` proved unsuccessful

Comment: Ok, try convert column to float, because I think it only seems there are numbers, but there are in real strings (object dtypes).

Comment: you need use `df['value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['value'], errors='coerce')` and you get `NaN` values, where are problematic values which cannot be converted to numbers.
You can also filter this values by:
`df[pd.to_numeric(df['value'], errors='coerce').isnull()]`.

Comment: I think `isnull()`, try `df = pd.DataFrame({'value':['8','a','1'],
                   'B':[4,5,6]})`.

Comment: solved. my initla table was flawed and in the way I gave it indeed had duplicates. sorry everyone for the waste of time.